# Application frozen on window drag

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to do some monitoring of an external resource (a national instruments acquisition system that produces points that are read by my program) while keeping the Gui responsive. To do this I'm calling *QCoreApplication::processEvents()* every cycle of the monitoring loop. **When I drag the main window with the mouse cursor the loop is halted until i release it, leading to loss of data.** I believe this behaviour is replicable in any scenario where *QCoreApplication::processEvents()* is called within an process intensive loop to keep the gui responsive.

Is there a way to run arround this issue or should I have implemented the monitoring cycle some other way?

Comment: The data acquisition needs to go into a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a separate `GUI Thread` and `Worker Thread`. Each Qt program has one thread known as the `GUI thread` when it is started. The Qt GUI must run in this thread. A `worker thread` is used to offload processing work (in your case monitoring of an external resource) from the main thread.

Read more about [Qt threading Basics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html) from the link.

Comment: Ok. I tought that might be the best way to deal with it. But it seems weird, as other events don't hang the processing loop, only the window drag/move. And even if I place the monitoring on another thread I predict the window would freeze the _information displaying loop_ anyway, because in my program the acquired data is displayed live.

Comment: Maybe if I could reimplement the move event and throw a _QCoreApplication::processEvents()_ in the middle. Any clues?

Comment: EDIT: I was able to subclass but it doesn't work the way I was thinking.

Comment: Please, *add relevant code* to your question if you are not happy with the answer. Note that if you press and hold down the mouse button on a widget then that widget grabs mouse events until you release the button. Pressing the mouse without releasing it is effectively the same as calling grabMouse(), i.e. other widgets get no mouse events at all.

Comment: Thank you talamaki for the unswer. I think you understood the question and gave the most relevent unswer. I'm not happy because it reveals I might not have done things correctly. But still, I'd like to be able to keep updating the gui while under a window move and even with the monitoring task on another thread.